# Simpsons episode with $1000

Tags: identify-this-episode, the-simpsons

I'm thinking of a Simpsons episode where the plot is triggered by Bart obtaining a $1000 bill from Mr Burns.

Does anyone remember which episode it is? I've been wracking my brain for ages.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The episode is "[The Regina Monologues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Regina_Monologues)" where Bart creates a museum for his found $1000 bill. This inspires the family to go to England for a holiday.

[image: An image of the $1,000 bill.]

Comment: Why stolen? From the [wikipedia page in the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Regina_Monologues), it's pretty clear Bart _found_ it, and the Simpsons even made an attempt to return it to its rightful owner: _"Mr. Burns withdraws a $1000 bill from an ATM, but he drops it and an updraft carries it away to the Simpsons' house, where it is found by Bart and Milhouse. Marge makes Bart and Homer put up fliers so that the person who lost the bill can reclaim it."_

Answer (score 21):

[The Regina Monologues (#EABF22 / SI-1417)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0701258/) 
Aired Nov 23rd 2003

> Mr. Burns loses a thousand-dollar bill that is quickly turned into the main display at the Museum of Modern Bart. After Burns shows up to reclaim his money, Bart realizes he still earned enough from charging admission to take the Simpsons to England. When they arrive, Marge begs Homer to make this an incident-free trip, which he actually succeeds at until he accidentally runs into the Queen. Now the only thing that will earn Homer a stay of execution is whether he can uncover the plot to poison her majesty. Meanwhile, Bart befriends Prince William. Guest stars Ian McKellan, J.K. Rowling, Jane Leeves, and Prime Minister Tony Blair.

Comment: that second to last sentence about the poison plot seems not at all like what's mentioned in the Wikipedia plot synopsis.

Comment: I recall this episode, I think the poison plot did indeed take place.